# MATLAB:saving different versions of program in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, version-control

I'm working on a project with MATLAB and the functions and structure of the project may need to change in next steps, but sometimes one of previous versions of program(which may be over-written) can be better than the latter ones.
as MATLAB requires functions to get saved with their own names changing function name and memorizing the version is a bit annoying.
is there any way to save all the versions of a function for further returns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think scientific programmers ought to use source code management systems like Subversion and Git just for this reason.  Keep versions of your input and data so you can recreate results at will.

I was never aware of the practice when I did finite element analysis for a living.  If I were to go back to it now I'd certainly be keeping all my code and input files in Git.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use this trick a lot, but recently I found this could slow down your code by quite a bit.

Say in the main script you need a function called `foo` -

```
y = foo(5);
```

.... and you have 2 versions of `foo`:

```
function y = foo_v1(x)
    y = x+1;
end

function y = foo_v2(x)
    y = x+2;
end
```

The trick is, create a function handle at the beginning of the main script.

```
useversion = 'v1';
switch useversion
    case 'v1'
        foo = @foo_v1;
    case 'v2'
        foo = @foo_v2;
end

y = foo(5);
```

To coordinate large number of functions, consider using [`str2func`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html)

Each time when you want to change the version to use, the only thing that needs changing is the string variable `useversion`.

---

But function handles definitely slow down the code, **significantly**. If this is a serious heavy-duty project, I would suggest `git`.